# Does tails leave any history on the live boot usb?

Tags: tails

I was just wondering if tails leaves any history on the bootable usb itself? I know most of the processes and etc are all done with the cpu and ram, and once the computer is turned off history is gone. But wasn't sure on the USB part? Does it leave any browser history or anything on the usb, if the usb ever got compromised?

Thanks

Comment: if you are still concerned about this and leery, you can use Tails via [LiveDVD](https://tails.boum.org/install/dvd-download/index.en.html).

Answer (score 1):

No. Tails stores all of it's data in RAM and doesn't writes data onto the liveboot stick (unless configured to do so).

See: https://tails.boum.org/about/index.en.html#index2h1

Answer (score 0):

You could checksum all the sectors of the partition before and after having used the stick: If the checksum changed, something was changed on the stick.

Maybe using a software like tripwire (http://www.linux-magazine.com/Online/Features/Detecting-Attackers-with-Tripwire).

But make sure to check the right partition (i.e. not the persistent one).